# screen.width vs. Device Real Resolution

Tags: javascript, mobile, screen-resolution

I was trying to understand about `screen.width` when viewing e.g. [New York Times](http://mobile.nytimes.com) on my Android and iOS devices. Here are what I found (all viewed at portrait orientation):

- `screen.width` returned 320 when I remote-debugged my [iPod touch](http://www.apple.com/ipod-touch/specs.html), which is supposed to have a 640x1136 resolution.
- `screen.width` returned 384 when viewed on my Nexus 4, which is supposed to have a 768x1280 resolution.

Shouldn't `screen.width` return the resolution of the device? If not, what JavaScript object could I use to reliably get the resolution info?

Comment: In case this relates to the _meta viewport_, the NYT site uses `<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1">`.

Comment: Were you able to come to a conclusion on this?

Comment: What is the reason you need the actual number on pixels on a mobile device?

Comment: I was trying to do a simple condition i.e. `if (screen.width < 640) { $('meta[name=viewport]').attr('content', 'width=640, initial-scale=.5, maximum-scale=.5'); }`

Answer (score 0):

What seems to be getting me the correct coordinates is `window.innerWidth` and `window.innerHeight`. I can guarantee they'll work, but they probably will. If they don't, make sure that the website isn't zoomed in (some mobile browsers zoom automatically)

Comment: `window.innerWidth` also returned 384. :( How to find out that the page is at the zoomed (in / out) state?

Answer (score 0):

What's basically going on here is that, to make sure that older sites render properly on these devices, Apple made the decision to report the original sizes when they moved to the retina display on the iPhone. Because of this precedence, Google made the same decision. If you are at your PC and it has a resolution of 1024x768, it will likely be a 10+ inch display. This would not translate well to a device that is only 4 or 5 inches diagonally, at least that's the rationale.

For a more in-depth look at this idea, I suggest you check out quirks mode's blog post about it, which you can find [here](http://www.quirksmode.org/blog/archives/2010/04/a_pixel_is_not.html)